# How to not merge webconfig file every merge event?

Tags: c#, asp.net, git, bitbucket

Our development team are using different webconfig settings like connectionstring, etc. for testing or development phase and sometimes pushing these changes accidentally so, this leads to big problems. After pushing, Jenkins apply changes and we waste a lot of time to find errors. We are using git control system via Bitbucket. How to prevent these problems?

And also I tried to gitattribute file like this but after, new branch push still merging it.

```
# Source https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings
# Set default behaviour, in case users don't have core.autocrlf set.
* text=auto

# Explicitly declare text files we want to always be normalized and 
converted 
# to native line endings on checkout.
---is it necessary to specify?

# Declare files that will always have CRLF line endings on checkout.
*.sln text eol=crlf

# Denote all files that are truly binary and should not be modified.
*.config binary
*.jpg binary
*.ico binary

core.autocrlf=true
```

Comment: Have a look at [transform web.config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/transform-webconfig?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Answer (score 0):

There is two main family of solutions :

1. Have a single configuration file and tell git to don't track (local) modifications on that file.

   git update-index --assume-unchanged
2. A more elegant solution is to have only a `connectionstring_template.conf` tracked in git (containing production code). `connectionstring.conf` file is added to your `.gitignore`. So when you deploy your code for the first time on a machine, you just have to copy and rename your template file, and tweak it as needed. Note that git doesn't track the configuration file, so you can't propagate a test configuration to the production environment. If you want to automatically update all conf file on production environment from template file, a simple script can do the job (launched manually or with git hooks).